# span of $AA^T$ is the same as $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ real matrix.

How do you prove that the span of columns of $AA^T$ is the same as columns of $A$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** I am using repeatedly the following property:  $b \in Col(B)$ if and only if $Bx=b$ is consistent.

$Col(AA^T) \subset Col(A)$ is clear.  We prove the other inclusion.

Let $b \in Col(A)$. Then, there exists some $x$ so that $Ax=b$.

Let $y=proj_{Col(A^T)}x$. This means that $y \in Col(A^T)$ and $x-y \perp Col(A^T)$.

Let $y= A^Tz$. We claim that $AA^Tz=b$.Indeed

$$AA^Tz=Ay \,.$$
and $x-y \perp Col(A^T)=Row(A) \Rightarrow A(x-y)=0 \Rightarrow Ay=Ax=b$.

**P.S.** This is just the basic idea behind why solving the Normal Equation solves the least square problems.

Comment: Stupid question, but why is the first inclusion clear?

Comment: @sidht - every column of AA^t is a combination of columns of A. So every combination of that is again in the col-span of A

Comment: why such $z$ exists, is $A$ "invertible"? but $A$ seems just a $m\times n$ matrix.

Comment: @Leo, what is 'that'?

Comment: @sidht - by "that" I mean a combination of columns of AA^t

Comment: Although @Coiacy provides a shorter proof, this answer gives an insight as to why this is true so I've chosen it.

Comment: @Leo I'm OK with that, as long as you believe it is correct, while I still have some doubts about this solution.

Comment: @sidht If $b \in Col(AA^T)$ then there exists some $x$ so that $AA^Tx=b$. But then $Ay=b$ where $y=A^Tx$. I'm using here the equivalence $b \in Col(A) \Leftrightarrow Ax=b$ is consistent.

Comment: @Coiacy $y$ is in the column space of a matrix $B$ if and only if $Bz=y$ is consistent. Use this for $B=A^T$.

Comment: @Coiacy Which step do you have doubts with?

Comment: @N.S. what do you mean by $proj_{Col(A^T)}x$, and why is it not empty?

Comment: @Coiacy It is the projection of $x$ on the Column space of $A$. And the column space cannot be empty because it contains at least the 0 vector.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks, but my question is, why such y exists? First, $y\in Col(A^T)$, and sencond, $x-y\perp Col(A^T)$. What guarantees its existence? That is confusing to me.

Comment: @Coiacy That is the orthogonal decomposition of $x$ with respect to the subspace $Col(A^T)$. $x$ can be written uniquely as $x=y+z$ with $y \in Col(A^T)$ and $z \perp Col(A^T)$. Then $y=\proj_{col(A^T)} x$ and $x-y =z \perp Col(A)$.

Comment: @N.S. Sorry about that, as this is a homework problem I did long time ago and I thought the typical way to solve was the solution I provided. Well, I am wrong and I like your idea.

Comment: @Coiacy I like your solution too, it is shorter. Often there are multiple ways to solve any math problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Note $AA^T$ is a $m\times m$ matrix, suppose $X$ is a $m \times 1$ vector, then
$$
AA^TX=0\quad \Rightarrow \quad X^TAA^TX=0\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad (X^TA)(X^TA)^T=0\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad X^TA=0
$$

Since $AA^TX=0 \Rightarrow X^TA=0$, we obtain $span(A)\subset span(AA^T)$, while $span(AA^T)\subset span(A)$ is trivial.

Comment: This is probably a useless comment, but in the first $\iff$, it is true under the assumption that $X$ is not the zero vector?

Comment: @sidht Thanks for your question, and I've edited my answer.

Comment: Can you conclude $span(A) \subset span(AA^T)$ from $AA^TX = 0 \Rightarrow X^TA = 0$ without doing a rank-nullity calculation?

Comment: @ZachL. Yes you are right, there is more to say, like the corresponding null space. Well, I just provide a hint, so I'd better not provide full details here.